# Unable to build Kubernetes in Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Trying to build and debug Kubernetes from source code - from this [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/running-locally.md#etcd)

But when running

```
sudo ./hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

I get error saying:

```
To ignore the vendor directory, use -mod=readonly or -mod=mod.
To sync the vendor directory, run:
        go mod vendor
```

If I do `go mod vendor` I get very many "No such file or directory":

```
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes'
find: ‘vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/examples/client-go/hack’: No such file or directory
find: ‘vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/examples/client-go/pkg/apis/cr’: No such file or directory
find: ‘vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/examples/client-go/pkg/apis/cr/v1’: No such file or directory
find: ‘vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/examples/client-go/pkg/client/clientset/versioned’: No such file or directory
find: ‘vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/examples/client-go/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/fake’: No such file or directory
```

How do you build/debug and run Kubernegtes from source code?

Comment: Seems like a perfectly legal question to ask on the [kubernetes community forum](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/) or the [kubernetes users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-users).

Comment: Not much responce over there - but thanks

Comment: silly question.. but any chance you have tried a fresh re-built? I had an issue like that once due to an intermittent disconnection on my network

Comment: Thanks for asking, I am starting from scratch each time I think I have a solution using a script.